# Codeigniter 3 index method behaving unexpectedly

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I have a CodeIgniter project on a subdomain. Now, When I visit `sub.example.com` it loads a `login page` and on successful login, it redirects to dashboard. Once logged in and session are in place visiting `sub.example.com/login/` will auto-redirect to the `dashboard page`. Now here's my problem. After successful login, visiting `sub.example.com` doesn't redirect anywhere it simply load the login page. But visiting `sub.example.com/index.php` does redirect me to the dashboard page.

For some reason, my index method is called or working properly.

Here my code.

> .htaccess

```
IndexIgnore *
php_value date.timezone Asia/Kolkata

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]


## Remove www from URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

## Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

> config.php

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "127.0.0.1") {
    $config['base_url'] = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
} else {
    $config['base_url'] = "https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}
```

> routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'root';
$route['root_controller'] = 'root';

/*API CONTROLLER*/
$route['api_controller'] = 'api';

/*Guest Controller*/
$route['guest_controller'] = 'guest';

/*Custom Routes*/

$route['dashboard/(:any)'] = 'root/dashboard/$1';

$route['search/(:any)'] = 'root/search/$1';
$route['search/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'root/search/$1/$2';

$route['export/(:any)'] = 'root/export/$1';
```

> root controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->default_data = array("project_name" => PROJECT_NAME);
        if ($this->router->method == "privacy_policy") {
            return;
        }

        $this->load->library('session');

        if ($this->router->method == "login") {
            if ($this->session->userdata("username")) {
                redirect(base_url("dashboard/"));
            }
        } else {
            if (!$this->session->userdata("username")) {
                redirect(base_url("login/"));
            }
        }

        //Set MYSQL timezone
        $this->db->query("SET time_zone = '+05:30'");
    }

    /**
     * Dashboard View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        redirect(base_url("/dashboard/"));
    }

    /**
     * Login View
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $data = $this->default_data;
        if ($_POST) {
            $username = $this->input->post("username");
            $plain_password = $this->input->post("password");
            $this->load->model("authenticate");
            if (!$this->authenticate->auth($username, $plain_password)) {
                $data['message'] = "Invalid Credentials";
            }
        }
        $this->load->view('login', $data);
    }
```

> Update

1. Forgot to mention that I am having this issue only on the remote server. On localhost it's working fine.

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']  is not return 127.0.0.1 is return 192.168.0... ip address , so your in logical error .directly use `echo $config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);  ` without if condition

Comment: Looks like you're rewriting to remove index from url. What's your `$config['index_page']` set to?

Comment: @AnandhukrishnaVR I know its returning 192... Its expected behavior. This shouldn't cause any issue. However, I tried your code without if block still the same issue. Plus, it adds index.php to the URL on redirect which I don't want.

Comment: @Kisaragi its set to `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';. How do I properly remove index.php from URL and still not cause any issue that I am having?

Comment: @AkashKumar you can remove `index.php` by creating `.htaccess`  with code `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: You already have the rewrite rule, set `config['index_page'] = "";`

Comment: @Kisaragi I removed rewrite rule from `.htaccess` and still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was some issue with files on the remote server. I don't exactly know if the files were different or corrupted but replacing the whole project on the remote server fixed the issue

Answer (score 5):

Hers is an idea - add this after you have loaded the session object:

```
    if ($this->session->userdata("username") && $this->router->method == "index") {
            redirect(base_url("dashboard/"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.* 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

if you visiting sub.example.com/index.php successfully then try this

```
public function login()
{
    $data = $this->default_data;
    if ($_POST) {
        $username = $this->input->post("username");
        $plain_password = $this->input->post("password");
        $this->load->model("authenticate");
        if (!$this->authenticate->auth($username, $plain_password)) {
            $data['message'] = "Invalid Credentials";
        }else{
            //go to dashboard function
            $this->index();
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('login', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Turns out there was some issue with files on the remote server. I don't exactly know if the files were different or corrupted but replacing the whole project on the remote server fixed the issue" --

@Akash You should compare your local and remote .htaccess files. I think that will explain your problem.